# input loses its margin when opacity of sibling changes

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='mdnew'>
<div class=' gblue mdtitle'>NEW TAG</div>
<input id='inpnew' type='text' autocomplete='off' maxlength=25 placeholder='NEW TAG'>
<div class='gblue leftcancel'>CANCEL</div>
<div class='gblue rightok' id='newok'>OK</div>
<div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

when input has focus (i.e. pointer is inside) and mouse is over `cancel` button - input loses its left margin !

complete code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5qperdzb/3/)

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `opacity` of `.leftcancel`,`rightok` on hover, its effecting to the sibling

remove that part and test

```
.leftcancel:hover, .rightok:hover{
    //opacity:0.8;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qperdzb/14/)

**Update :**

To make it work with opacity, add `position` and `z-index` to `.leftcancel` and `.rightok`

The opacity you're setting on `.leftcancel` and `.rightok` is creating a new stacking context, and stacking contexts affect z-indexes. Since you didn't specify z-indexes manually, they're being auto assigned, and `.leftcancel` and `.rightok` has a higher value than `#inpnew` because it comes later in the markup.

Reference : [W3C Color Module](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#transparency)

> If an element with opacity less than 1 is not positioned, implementations must paint the layer it creates, within its parent stacking context, at the same stacking order that would be used if it were a positioned element with ‘z-index: 0’ and ‘opacity: 1’.

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#mdnew{
 position:fixed;
 z-index:2;
 width:300px;
 left:calc(50% - 150px);
 top:63px;
 background: red;
 border-radius:5px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#inpnew{
   
    
 display:block;
 width:calc(100% - 28px);
 margin:14px auto;
 line-height:21px;
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid #999;
 border-radius:5px;
 padding:0 7px;
}

.leftcancel{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
 float:left;
 width:50%;
 line-height:23px;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
}

.rightok{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
 float:right;
 width:50%;
 line-height:23px;
 cursor:pointer;
 text-align:center;
}

.leftcancel:hover, .rightok:hover{
 opacity:0.8;
}

.gblue{
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #003b61, #0099cc);
 background: linear-gradient(to top, #003b61, #0099cc);
 color:white;
 letter-spacing:0.5px;
}

.mdtitle{
 line-height:23px;
 text-align:center;
 letter-spacing:0.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id='mdnew'>
<div class=' gblue mdtitle'>NEW TAG</div>
<input id='inpnew' type='text' autocomplete='off' maxlength=25 placeholder='NEW TAG'>
<div class='gblue leftcancel'>CANCEL</div>
<div class='gblue rightok' id='newok'>OK</div>
<div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

Updated fiddle is : https://jsfiddle.net/5qperdzb/16/

Comment: `opacity` should means `opacity` and nothing more. Anyway, you've find the  source of the problem. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `input` with `div` and it will work.

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
}

#mdnew {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    width:300px;
    left:calc(50% - 150px);
    top:63px;
    background: red;
    border-radius:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#inpnew {
    display:block;
    width:calc(100% - 28px);
    margin:14px auto;
    line-height:21px;
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid #999;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:0 7px;
}

.leftcancel {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    line-height:23px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}

.rightok {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    line-height:23px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:center;
}

.leftcancel:hover, .rightok:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
}

.gblue {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #003b61, #0099cc);
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #003b61, #0099cc);
    color:white;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;
}

.mdtitle {
    line-height:23px;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:0.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mdnew">
    <div class=" gblue mdtitle">NEW TAG</div>
    <div>
        <input id="inpnew" type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="25" placeholder="NEW TAG" >
    </div>
    <div class="gblue leftcancel">CANCEL</div>
    <div class="gblue rightok" id="newok">OK</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5qperdzb/9/)..

Comment: it works, but how to explain? why is an extra div needed?

Answer (score 1):

If you're calculating input's width as `100% - 28px` then it's safe to just use `14px` for `margin-left` and `margin-right`:

```css
#inpnew {
    margin: 14px;
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks. But I expect someone to explain why original margins work before focus, and don't work after receiving focus. And why is a `hover` over a button - a triger for changing margins ?